# datepicker not modified according to options set

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the following script for my datepicker:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var date_input=$('input[name="Date"]'); //date input has the name "Date"

        date_input.datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
        });
    });
</script>
```

which is working properly.

However, when I try to set some additional options, those changes do not appear implemented in the calendar.

For instance, adding the following line after `autoclose: true` will not show two months

```
numberOfMonths: 2
```

Or adding the following two lines will not limit the dates that can be selected:

```
minDate: new Date(2016, 12 - 1, 16),
maxDate: new Date(2017, 1 - 1, 7)
```

That means, the following script behaves exactly the same as the one at the beginning of the question:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var date_input=$('input[name="Date"]'); //date input has the name "Date"

        date_input.datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            minDate: new Date(2016, 12 - 1, 16),
            maxDate: new Date(2017, 1 - 1, 7)
        });
    });
</script>
```

I thought that maybe I have the same script somewhere else duplicated, but it does not seem to be the case, since if I change the format from `format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'` to `format: 'yyyy/mm/dd'`, this change is actually visible.

Why then am I not able to set some additional properties in my datepicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems all the codes are working fine. Check this code and compare with yours, may be you have called datepicker() function more than once for that name field. Check your js and html file both. If you call more than once it won't show the result properly. But basic date picker works for the first call, that's why rest of the functionality doesn't work.

[Click here to see the pen from codepen](http://codepen.io/afikur/pen/gLEBGJ)

```js
$( function() {
    var date_input=$('input[name="Date"]'); //date input has the name "Date"

        date_input.datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            minDate: new Date(2016, 12 - 1, 16),
            maxDate: new Date(2017, 1 - 1, 7)
        });
  } );
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="Date"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Afikur . I've cross-checked and played around, but I did not find any duplication or calling the function twice. 

In addition, in the snippet you created I can see the two months and the date limitation are properly displayed, but the `format` option is not properly implemented (or at least I see it as "dd/mm/yyyy" as output format instead of the "yyyy-mm-dd" specified). It seems like the same problem I am having...?

Comment: I found there is **no property** named `format: yy-mm-dd` in the API, instead there is  a property name `dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"` , which works as expected.

Comment: Yes! I don't know where exactly I had the duplication, but after playing around for hours, I managed to remove it. Afterwards I was having the same problem as you, and the change from `format` to `dateFormat` solved it. I guess the name of this [option](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) was changed at some point... Strange that in my initial code `format` was working properly, but anyway, good that now is working! Thanks!